# Installing Ubuntu on Dual BIOS/UEFI PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I had a Dual BIOS/UEFI PC with Windows 10 and Debian 8 installed and working perfectly. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20 on the Debian 8 partition. When 'Installation type', Windows was not shown at the options, so I chose Something else.
At the partition selection, I chose Debian partition as /. When starting the installation I got the message:

No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail.
Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.

So, I added an EFI partition of 1024Mb but then, the installation starts but after some time it says something like 'It failed trying to mount a vfat filesystem at /boot/efi.

How could I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is Windows and was old Debian installed in UEFI boot mode? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. If Windows fast start up is on, the installer may not see your ESP nor NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Ubuntu 20 implies Ubuntu Core 20 (or another *yy* release), which is a different product to the *yy.mm* format 20.04 you possibly mean. Please clarify (Ubuntu has used *yy* releases for a different product since 2016)   Ensure you install the correct system, as Ubuntu Core 20 is a very different system to Debian, Debian is closest to the *yy.mm* format releases (which use *debs*, *yy* releases in Ubuntu use *snaps* only)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
At the end, I tried without EFI system partition and it was all fine. I'm not sure why the installation setup showed that scaring message but finally such partition was not necessary.